# Software for Analyzing text (Cloud, Desktop or Mobile) and extract keywords and classify

Tags: text, cloud, classification, keyword

Can someone tell me what are the most interesting options for analyzing specific texts for extracting and classifying keywords. What I look for is essentially the speed of response. Someone with experience can tell me what are the solutions in the cloud, web services, whether open source or proprietary.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There's a not too old [Quora-post](http://www.quora.com/What-are-good-tools-to-extract-key-words-and-or-topics-tags-from-a-random-paragraph-of-text) were several links to open source and commercial APIs, toolkits, etc. are provided.

For example:

- [Stanford topic modeling tool](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/) (open source)
- [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/keyword/) (commercial)
- ...

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.